# Detect when app is minimized (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa

I am building a mobile game and I have a NSTimer for my stopwatch.  Everything works fine, except when I minimize the app (press home screen), or when it is interrupted by, say a phone call, the NSTimer continues running in the background, when the application is not in use.

I need to invalidate this timer when the app is minimized/interrupted and create a new timer when the app is resumed.  What methods handle when the app is minimized and resumed?

Comment: "Minimized" is the wrong term.  You want `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive`.  Possibly you also want `applicationDidEnterBackground`.  These are all delegate methods of `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: In addition to calls to the app delegate you also get notifications. Read up on application life cycle here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can invalidate timer in AppDelegate in UIApplication delegate method **applicationDidEnterBackground** this way,

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

And create a new timer in method **applicationWillEnterForeground**